# pytest can't find helper modules located under the tests directory

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, pytest, setup.py

When using PyCharm to launch my tests I have no import problems at all, but if I do it in the terminal pytest complains about modules that cannot find. Precisely those under `tests/tools`.

Project folder structure:

```
src/
    app/

tests/
    end_to_end/ # End to end/Acceptance tests
    tools/      # Helper modules used by some tests
    unit        # Unit tests

setup.py
```

Relevant parts of `setup.py`:

```
setup(...
      packages=find_packages('src'),
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      install_requires=['requests'],
      test_suite='tests',
      tests_require=[
          'flexmock',
          'pytest',
          'wsgi_intercept'
      ])
```

Import line that fails when executing `py.test tests/end_to_end`, no matter if the virtualenv is active or not. Modules imported from the `app` package are fine:

```
from tests.tools.foomodule import Foo # Fails
from app.barmodule import Bar         # Doesn't fail
```

I had to install my package with `pip install -e packagename` in order to be *available* for pytest when running tests from the command line. I suppose I will have to add the `tools` folder as a package in my `setup.py`, but this feels ugly to me because that modules are only for aiding in the testing process and aren't meant to be distributed.

On the other hand I could launch my tests with `python setup.py test` following the [integration advices from pytest website](https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#integrating-with-distutils-python-setup-py-test).

Comment: Do you create a virtual environment with Pycharm?

Comment: I'm using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv) to manage my development environments. The configuration in PyCharm points the project interpreter to a specific virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you do not have `__init__.py` in your `tests` and/or `tests/tools` directory.
If missed python do see them as packages and is not able to import them.
You can:

- add `__init__.py`  (BAD see [here](https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.3/goodpractises.html)
- add tests/tools to your PYTHONPATH in your `conftest.py` and import a file (from `import tests.tools.MODULE` to `import MODULE`)

Comment: I've accepted your answer because you've tried to solve the problem without touching the original directory layout :)

Comment: but manipulating the Python path, especially if it changes the semantic name of the import, is much worse...

Comment: @ely this is true only if you do not follow pytest best practices ( https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.3/goodpractises.html). If your tests are not importable pytest already change your pythonpath and the solution is perfectly fine. If your tests are importable there is no need for this solution.

Comment: Letting pytest transparently change the path, which is a documented an expected thing pytest does (or even doing it explictly with `python -m pytest`) is totally fine. Adding your own application code that manually changes the path for the sake of importing things, and further does so in a way where the path to the module is not reflected in the fully qualified import name unless you know in your mind what modification to the Python path was used, is a bad pattern that should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to import modules residing outside `src` folder I went to "Project settings" in PyCharm, and there in "Project structure" I marked `tests/end_to_end` and `tests/unit` as [*source* folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/project-structure-dialog.html).

I also changed my mind and decided to put my helper modules inside those folders. This way I can import them directly and my tests run fine in terminal too because the current working directory is always added to the `PYTHONPATH`.